# bash command "read -r" fails sometimes

Tags: bash

I have a small script to read avail of filesystem to check how much space is left in the filesystem and it works sometimes, but fails for unknown reasons. When it fails, it never recovers. I can't see what causes avail to remain unset. Appreciate if someone can give an insight into the problem.

```
while :; do
    str="$(df  | grep '/var/log' )"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "Somethin's wrong"
    fi
    if [ -z "$str" ]; then
            echo null str
            sleep 1
            continue
    fi
    read -r map size used avail use mount <<< $str
    if [ -z "$avail" ]; then
        echo Iter:$ext: mount: $mount avail:$avail size:$size, use:$use, used:$used
    fi
    if [ $avail -eq 0 ]; then
        echo Iter:$ext: mount: $mount avail:$avail size:$size, use:$use, used:$used
        break
    else
        sleep 1
    fi
done
```

The failure log:

```
+ :
++ grep /var/log
++ df
+ str='/dev/mapper/vg--db--sda-dat.log.1           495844   138915    331329  30% /var/log'
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ '[' -z '/dev/mapper/vg--db--sda-dat.log.1           495844   138915    331329  30% /var/log' ']'
+ read -r map size used avail use mount
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ echo Iter:6: mount: avail: size:, use:, used:
Iter:6: mount: avail: size:, use:, used:
+ '[' -eq 0 ']'
./run.sh: line 83: [: -eq: unary operator expected
+ sleep 1
+ :
++ df
++ grep /var/log
+ str='/dev/mapper/vg--db--sda-dat.log.1           495844   138916    331328  30% /var/log'
+ '[' 0 -ne 0 ']'
+ '[' -z '/dev/mapper/vg--db--sda-dat.log.1           495844   138916    331328  30% /var/log' ']'
+ read -r map size used avail use mount
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ echo Iter:6: mount: avail: size:, use:, used:
Iter:6: mount: avail: size:, use:, used:
+ '[' -eq 0 ']'
./run.sh: line 83: [: -eq: unary operator expected
+ sleep 1
+ :
```

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? There were various bugs involving unquoted parameters expansions in here strings that were fixed in versions 4.3 and 4.4. Specifically, all the fields are being stored in `map`, leaving the rest of the variables unset. `read -r map size used avail use mount <<< "$str"` should work, though.

Comment: the `$ext` version is empty in both debug itterations you have posted, and causing the error message `./run.sh: line 83: [: -eq: unary operator expected`.  I don't see any code like `ext=Something` that would set the value. Is that a typo, or a bug? ;-). Good luck.

Comment: ext was set prior to entering this code

Answer (score 1):

You correctly test

```
if [ -z "$avail" ]; then
```

but even if $avail is empty, you still execute

```
if [ $avail -eq 0 ]; then
```

which results in the error message. Put it into an

```
if [ -z "$avail" ]; then
...
elif [ $avail -eq 0 ]; then
...
fi
```